# Не работает поиск в потоке Selenium

Tags: c#, многопоточность, selenium

Реализовал не без помощи форумчан поток на *Selenium C#*. При работе в потоке перестал работать поиск элементов `FindElement()`.Если запустить вне потока все работает хорошо. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

```
namespace lessons
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://yandex.ru");
            for{
            var y = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]")).GetAttribute("outerHTML");
             var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
             htmlDoc.LoadHtml(y);
             var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div");
             string z  = htmlBody.OuterHtml;
             string[] d = z.Split(' ','=','"');
             Thread OneHandes = new Thread(OneBoys);
             OneHandes.Start(driver);
             }
        }
        public static void OneBoys(object obj)
        {
             IWebDriver driver = (IWebDriver)obj;
             var apfa= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[1]")).GetAttribute("outerHTML");
             var htmlDocalfa = new HtmlDocument();
             htmlDocalfa.LoadHtml(alfa);
             var htmlBodyalfa = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div");
             string talfa  = htmlBody.OuterHtml;
             string[] dalfa = z.Split(' ','=','"');
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых я не уверен, что `ChromeDriver` можно дёргать сразу из многих потоков, это надо проверять. А во-вторых вы запускаете треды, но не делаете ничего с результатами их работы, а главное - не ждёте их завершения. Вы их просто запустили - и забыли о них. Возможно, ваш `Main` просто заканчивается раньше, чем треды успевают хотя бы начать работать. Если хотите делать именно через `Tread`, то собирайте все созданные потоки в список и потом им всем по списку делайте `Join`. Хотя раз у вас `for`проще использовать `Parallel.For` вместо ручного создания потоков.

Comment: Можете ради эксперимента вставить `Console.ReadKey()` в самый конец кода метода `Main`.

Comment: А вообще что-то я не пойму что у вас за `for` такой, что-то тут не то )  Тело есть, а где условия?!

Comment: С циклом все хорошо(for(;;){}) просто ошибка когда писал вопрос.Спасибо , буду пробовать.

Comment: aepot Вставил , выдает ошибку при поиске элементы

Comment: @Keks Какую именно ошибку? Обновляйте сразу вопрос при появлении новых данных, пишите там всю информацию. Больше информации - проще вам помочь. И `for` исправьте заодно

Comment: Зачем вы создали второй аккаунт? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1266482/373567 Твинководство не приветствуется на StackOverflow.